# How 按 in 请按从小到大的顺序排列这些数字 works?

Tags: grammar

I found a following sentence from the official textbook of hsk4.

> 请按从小到大的顺序排列这些数字

The problem for me is understand how **按** works in the above sentence.

I've read the sentence as "Please (re)order the numbers in ascending order."

For me, I think that we can omit **按** from the sentence.

Please teach me about it

Comment: 清 should be 请 (unless it's a name or something like that).

Comment: I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

按 is short for 按照 (according to/ following)

- 清从小到大的顺序排列这些数字 = please arrange these numbers in ascending order
- 清**按**从小到大的顺序排列这些数字 = please arrange these numbers **according to/ following** ascending order

> For me, I think that we can omit 按 from the sentence.

Yes, you can remove 按 and the sentence would still make sense. It is just two different ways to say the same thing --> "in ascending order" and "following ascending order" are basically the same

Comment: Yes, grammatically nothing wrong to omit 按, but without it, the sentence "sounds" a bit colloquial.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it makes sense to remove the 按。 It sounds really weird. If you have to omit 按，you should also omit 的顺序

请从小到大排列这些数字.

It is the same principle as correcting "Please (re)order the numbers <del>in</del> ascending order." to "Please (re)order the numbers ascending-ly"